# Node-Red Select Query to Update Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-red

I've been trying several different ways but can't seem to figure out how to properly run an UPDATE after getting the results of the SELECT query.

I know how to do a query on it's own, but doing the handoff is confusing me.

`msg.payload.EXT` is the value coming from a GET post which is 102 and shows.

Error I have right now is

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'STATUS' of undefined"

```
msg.topic = "SELECT STATUS FROM outtbl_domainname WHERE EXT = '" + msg.payload.EXT + "'";
var theBitYouWantIs = msg.payload[0].STATUS;

if (theBitYouWantIs===0) {
    msg.topic = "UPDATE outtbl_domainname SET STATUS = '1' WHERE EXT = '102'";
    return msg;
}
else if (theBitYouWantIs===1){
    msg.topic = "UPDATE outtbl_domainname SET STATUS = '0' WHERE EXT = '102'";
    return msg;
}
```

UPDATE:
[image]

SELECT:

```
msg.topic = "SELECT STATUS FROM outtbl_domainname WHERE EXT = '" + msg.payload.ext + "'";
```

UPDATE:

```
if (msg.payload[0].STATUS===0) {
    msg.topic = "UPDATE outtbl_domainname SET STATUS = '1' WHERE EXT = '102'";
    return msg;
}
else if (msg.payload[0].STATUS==1){
    msg.topic = "UPDATE outtbl_domainname SET STATUS = '0' WHERE EXT = '102'";
    return msg;
}
```

I'm guessing you are meant to split the two?

No longer getting any errors but not getting an updates to the DB.